# VS2010 License Error in Design View

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a VS2010 solution that gets an error on on the controls in design view.  The error when it is rendered in design view says "An unhandled exception has occurred.  unable to locate license assembly."  This occurs even on simple controls such as an ASP.NET Textbox.  Any ideas what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed a Infragistics product and it without a Developer Licence.
Here a solution for a case liek your

> I looked for a solution to this all day yesterday, and finally figured out 
>   how to fix this for myself. Re-installed VS 2005 and Infragistics at least 3 
>   times and that did nothing for me.
>
> My setup is Vista 64, VS 2005 and Infragistics 7.2.
>
> My fix was to download SubInACL from here:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E8BA3E56-D8FE-4A91-
>   93CF-ED6985E3927B&displaylang=en
>
> And create a .cmd file with the following contents (You may need to change 
>   the first line if you are not running a 64-bit OS):
>
> cd /d "%programfiles% (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools"
>   subinacl /subkeyreg 
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Infragistics /grant=administrators=f /grant=users=f /grant=
>   system=f
>   subinacl /subkeyreg 
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Infragistics.License /grant=administrators=f /grant=users=f
>    /grant=system=f
>
> Then double click the file to run it. For some reason permissions weren't 
>   correctly set for the Infragistics registry keys to access them during 
>   design time.

[Original Post](http://forums.archive.infragistics.com/readmessage?id=%3C7cb764%2426fc29ba%24a628@news.infragistics.com%3E&group=infragistics.products.netadvantage.windowsforms.general)